# How to unselect a value from ngx-select-dropdown for multiple as false? (duplicate quesiton) but no question provided

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-select-dropdown

I am facing the same issue detailed given to this link.  [How to unselect a value from ngx-select-dropdown for multiple as false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397257/how-to-unselect-a-value-from-ngx-select-dropdown-for-multiple-as-false)

I could not find any answer.

here is my code.

```
<div class="controls">
     <ngx-select-dropdown (change)="changesavedSearchs($event)" [multiple]="false" [config]="config_saved_search" [options]="dropdownSaved_searchs"></ngx-select-dropdown>
</div>

 config_saved_search  ={
    displayKey:"name", //if objects array passed which key to be displayed defaults to description
    search:true, //true/false for the search functionlity defaults to false,
    height: '250px', //height of the list so that if there are more no of items it can show a scroll defaults to auto. With auto height scroll will never appear
    placeholder:'Select Your previous Search', // text to be displayed when no item is selected defaults to Select,
    customComparator: ()=>{}, // a custom function using which user wants to sort the items. default is undefined and Array.sort() will be used in that case,
    limitTo: 0, // number thats limits the no of options displayed in the UI (if zero, options will not be limited)
    moreText: 'more', // text to be displayed whenmore than one items are selected like Option 1 + 5 more
    noResultsFound: 'No results found!', // text to be displayed when no items are found while searching
    searchPlaceholder:'Select Your previous Search', // label thats displayed in search input,
    searchOnKey: 'name', // key on which search should be performed this will be selective search. if undefined this will be extensive search on all keys
    clearOnSelection: false, // clears search criteria when an option is selected if set to true, default is false
    inputDirection: 'ltr' // the direction of the search input can be rtl or ltr(default)
  }
```